# XML schema php validation decimal number error

Tags: php, xsd, domdocument

I have this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="errorType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:totalDigits value="28"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="16"/>
            <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxExclusive value="1000000000000"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="TEST">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="newElement" type="errorType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <newElement>123456789012.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>12345678901.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>1234567890.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789.1234567890123456</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789.500000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>1234567890.500000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>12345678901.500000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789012.50000000000003</newElement>

</TEST>
```

if I validate it using php DOMDocument schemaValidate function i get an error on decimal numbers greater than 27 digits total. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Complete code:

```
<?php


function libxml_display_error($error)
{
    $return = "<br/>\n";
    switch ($error->level) {
        case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
            $return .= "<b>WARNING:</b> $error->message ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
            $return .= "<b>ERROR:</b> $error->message ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
            $return .= "<b>FATAL:</b> $error->message ";
            break;
    }
    $return .= " on line <b>$error->line</b>\n";
    return $return;
}

function libxml_display_errors() {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print libxml_display_error($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}

$xsd = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="errorType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:totalDigits value="28"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="16"/>
            <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxExclusive value="1000000000000"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="TEST">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="newElement" type="errorType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';

$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <newElement>123456789012.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>12345678901.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>1234567890.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789.5000000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789.1234567890123456</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789.500000000000003</newElement>  <!-- VALID -->
    <newElement>1234567890.500000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>12345678901.500000000000003</newElement>
    <newElement>123456789012.50000000000003</newElement>
</TEST>
';
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $xmlObj = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlObj->loadXML($xml);
    $xmlObj->schemaValidateSource($xsd) ;
print_r (libxml_display_errors());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) change this label to whatever value you like

```
<xs:totalDigits value="28"/>
```

b) round the numbers to be smaller than the restriction (probably your numbers are 29 digits including the decimal point)

just acomplish any restriction that the schema requires

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:totalDigits value="28"/>
            <xs:fractionDigits value="16"/>
            <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxExclusive value="1000000000000"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Comment: The error is not in schema declaration but in php handling decimal numbers, try upper code.

Comment: read please...I wrote b) round the numbers to be smaller than the restriction

Comment: use round() function to get the numbers the desired length

Comment: I don't want to round(). I have been given a number with 28 digits, schema accepts that number, but php has restriction and validates wrong but should validate right, if I use round() taht won't be the number I'we been given.

Comment: you don't want to round, don't do it, you'll never make your code work unless you use strings. php float type precission is 15 digits

Comment: so I guess your problem is that you're not enforcing the restriction. you are using 28 digit numbers plus the decimal point, that's 29...so round the last number and try

Comment: again a) change the schema   b) round

Comment: But is there a way to increase precision?

Comment: read about php data types, ranges cannot be modified, they are stored in a certain number of bits, that provide you a range for each kind.

Comment: use strings insteads of numbers

Comment: Yes, that could be the only way, to use strings an regexp, but I cannot do that in an xml scheme, I cannot give my users a field for currency and that they need to enter string, it's silly. I think I need to rethink my app logic and do I really need 28 digits.

Comment: what do you need 28 digits for??